# Can we sync a SharePoint list which have Calendar view inside outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, outlook

I have a SharePoint custom list inside our SharePoint online site, and I add to it the Calendar view, as follow:

[image]

Now can we sync this list to our outlook calendars? and/or create a `.ics` invite from it?